# Change styling of error messages for jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

Is there any way to change the colors, font etc of the error messages of the jQuery validate form plug-in?

Answer (score 2):

Using that plugin, you can also specify whatever class you want to be used for the error state.

```
$('.selector').validate({
    errorClass: 'newError'
});
```

There are also highlight and unhighlight options that allow for more complicated styling to be applied to the element containing the error, such as:

```
$('.selector').validate({
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).fadeOut(function() {
            $(element).fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the bassistance.de plugin there is an associated class with each of the warnings popup. So all you would need to do is css changes to these classes. `label.warning` or `label.error` would be the selector to be able to change the styling for warnings. I was able to figure this out by firebugging the warnings that popup on one of the demos for this plugin.

Comment: I actually downloaded the compressed file from bassistance.de and i didn't find the file jquery.validate.package.js as it was suggested in a tutorial, so i downloaded it from another source and I just dragged that file in my project folder (whihc doesn't contain the bassistance.de files).

Comment: @MohamedTurki After you included it in your project does the plugin function correctly and give you errors that show next to the inputs?

Comment: Yeah it does even without adding the bassistance.de files !

Comment: show your html code I bet you are referencing a global url that has the code on it.